# dict comprehension how do i get the value of a key divided by a value of the same key but in a different dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries
how can i get a dictionary  that has the values divided buy the the value of the same key but in the other dictionary  ?

```
stat_dict = {'good': 6537048, 'evil': 32000, 'neutral': 69467, 'nihilist': 81977, 'cool': 771180}

count_dict = {'good': 2, 'evil': 2, 'neutral': 2, 'nihilist': 2, 'cool': 2}
```

this what I am looking for
an example for 'good'

```
avg_dict = {'good': 6537048/2}
```

i wrote this

```
avg_dict = {k:stat_dict[s_lst[2]]/count_dict[s_lst[2]] for k,v in stat_dict.items()}
```

but this gave

```
{'good': 385590.0, 'evil': 385590.0, 'neutral': 385590.0, 'nihilist': 385590.0, 'cool': 385590.0}
```

Comment: `avg_dict = {k: v / count_dict[k] for k,v in stat_dict.items()}`?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
for key in stat_dict.keys():
    avg_dict[key] = stat_dict[key]/count_dict[key]
```

?

Or are there keys in stat_dict that won't be in count_dict?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the Dict [items method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_items.asp).

This will give you access to the key and value in your first dictionary:

```
{ key: value / count_dict[key] for (key, value) in stat_dict.items() }
```

See [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) for more!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k:v/count_dict[k] for k,v in stat_dict.items()}
```

output:

```
{'good': 3268524.0,
 'evil': 16000.0,
 'neutral': 34733.5,
 'nihilist': 40988.5,
 'cool': 385590.0}
```

Comment: hey lets  say i am dividing by zero is there a way using try\except to replace the value of the key with 0.0 ?

Comment: No try/expect in a comprehension, but you can do `{k:0 if count_dict[k] == 0 else (v/count_dict[k]) ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
avg_dict = {k:v/count_dict[k] for k,v in stat_dict.items()}
```

Comment: The 'for k,v in stat.dict.items()' gives you everything you need except the corresponding value from count_dict. So you use the k key to pull the missing value as count_dict[k].